# Operator Precedence - Expression Evaluation

Tags: c, operator-precedence

For the following code snippet I get the output as `1`. I want to know how it came?

```
void main()
{
int x=10,y=20,z=5,i;
i=x<y<z;
printf("%d",i);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`i=x<y<z;`, gets interpreted as `i=(x<y)<z`, which in turn gets interpreted as `i=1<z`, which evaluates to 1.

Comment: Seems to be a rather common mistake, at least GCC (probably other compilers, too) prints out a warning, if warnings are enabled: `warning: comparisons like 'X<=Y<=Z' do not have their mathematical meaning`

Answer (score 2):

10 is less than 20, resulting in 1, and 1 is less than 5, resulting in 1. C doesn't chain relational operators as some other languages do.

Answer (score 1):

It operates as follows:
Since `<` is a logical expression, `x<y` i.e `10<20` is true i.e 1. So it becomes `1<z` i.e `1<5` which is again true i.e. 1 which is assigned to `i`. So `i` is 1.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your code evaluates as:

```
void main()
{
    int x=10,y=20,z=5,i;
    i=((x<y)<z); //(x<y) = true = 1, (1 < 5) = true
    printf("%d",i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what output did you want?

In C,

```
i = 2 < 3; //i == 1.
i = 4 < 3; //i == 0.
```

> If condition evaluates to false, value returned is 0, and 1 otherwise.
>   Also, x < y < z will be evaluated as ((x < y) < z).

Answer (score 0):

```
x<y // 1 as (10 < 20) will return 1
result of(x<y)<z // 1 as (1<5) will return 1
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ doesn't support multi-part comparisons like that.

```
x < y < z
```

is interpreted as

```
(x < y) < z
```

or that is, determine if `x < y`, then see if that *boolean* is less than `z`.

There's some discussion on *why* that is [over at the software engineering StackExchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/316969/12319).

When you find yourself trying to do this, instead you need to write it as two separate comparisons joined by a boolean:

```
(x < y) && (y < z)
```