# order of evaluation of operands

Tags: c++, c, c++11, expression, operator-precedence

In the expression `a + b`, is `a` guaranteed to be evaluated before `b`, or is the order of evaluation unspecified? I think it is the latter, but I struggle to find a definite answer in the standard.

Since I don't know whether C handles this different from C++, or if evaluation order rules were simplified in C++11, I'm gonna tag the question as all three.

Comment: +1 Because I don't see any reason for this to be downvoted. Infact this might serve as a very good faq, where we have relevant quotes from c99, c++03 and c++11 standards at one place.

Comment: @Als: didn't downvote it yet, but some research (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points) would have been good.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In C++, for user-defined types `a + b` is a function call, and the standard says:

> > §5.2.2.8 - [...] The order of evaluation of function arguments is **unspecified**. [...]

For normal operators, the standard says:

> > §5.4 - Except where noted, the order of evaluation of operands of individual operators and subexpressions of individual expressions, and the order in which side effects take place, is **unspecified**. [...]

These haven't been changed for C++11. However, the wording changes in the second one to say that the order is "*unsequenced*" rather than unspecified, but it is essentially the same.

I don't have a copy of the C standard, but I imagine that it is the same there as well.

Comment: CodeMonkey, already poosted the quote from the c99 standard as an comment under my answer.

Answer (score 11):

It is **Unspecified**.

**Reference - C++03 Standard:**

**Section 5: Expressions, Para 4:**

> except where noted [e.g. special rules for && and ||], the order of evaluation of operands of individual operators and subexpressions of individual expressions, and the order in which side effects take place, is **Unspecified**.

Comment: 5.2 does not seem like the right section... I am looking at it now - edit oops I am looking at C99 spec it is 6.5

Comment: @Code Monkey: Oops, Added that quote belongs to C++03.

Comment: In C99 it is at 6.5. "The grouping of operators and operands is indicated by the syntax.72) Except as specified
later (for the function-call (), &&, ||, ?:, and comma operators), the order of evaluation
of subexpressions and the order in which side effects take place are both unspecified."

Answer (score 1):

It is unspecified. C and C++ follow the same logic in selecting sequence points:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point

Comment: Its not *undefined*. Its *unspecified*. The Standard makes a difference between these two terminologies.

Answer (score 1):

C++0x FDIS section 1.9 "Program Execution" §15 is similar to the corresponding paragraph in C++03, just reworded to accommodate the conceptual change from "sequence points" to "being sequenced":

> Except where noted, evaluations of operands of individual operators and of subexpressions of individual expressions are unsequenced.

Answer (score 0):

For C: "Order of operations is not defined by the language. The compiler is free to evaluate such expressions in any order, if the compiler can guarantee a consistent result." [...] "Only the sequential-evaluation (,), logical-AND (&&), logical-OR (||), conditional-expression (? :), and function-call operators constitute sequence points and therefore guarantee a particular order of evaluation for their operands."

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bxt6kc4.aspx

The way this is organized in that article, it seems to indicate this applies to C++ too, which is confirmed by the answer to this question: [Operator Precedence vs Order of Evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473107/operator-precedence-vs-order-of-evaluation).

Answer (score 0):

According to the current [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), C11, it also specifies that the order of evaluation of subexpressions (`a` and `b` in this case) is indeterminate.  In fact, this order doesn't even have to be the same if the same expression is evaluated multiple times.

From section 6.5:

> The grouping of operators and operands is indicated by the
>   syntax.<sup>85)</sup> Except as specified later, side effects and
>   **value computations of subexpressions are unsequenced.**<sup>86)</sup>
>
> ---
>
> 86)   In an expression that is evaluated more than once during the
>   execution of a program, **unsequenced and indeterminately  sequenced 
>   evaluations  of  its  subexpressions  need  not  be  performed 
>   consistently  in different evaluations.**