# Recursive Palindrome Test

Tags: c++, recursion, character-arrays

I have a prototype restriction of `bool pal(char str[], int length)` and I need to test whether a string the user entered is a palindrome or not. The code I have is:

```
bool pal(char str[], int length)
{
    if(*str == str[length - 1])
    {
        pal(str+1, length-1);
    }
    else
    {
        return false
    }
    return true;
}
```

but it seems to only be testing if the first character is the same as the last character. I think this is because my array (start point) isn't incrementing but I'm not sure why.

Comment: Please paste your actual code -- this doesn't look like it should even compile (e.g., `*pal == pal[length - 1]` should undoubtedly be `*str == str[length - 1]`).

Comment: You forgot about an extra character you cut off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose it's probably due to some deep-seated aversion to `if` statements, but if it were up to me, I think I'd write the code something like this:

```
bool pal(char *str, size_t len) { 
    return len <2 || (str[0] == str[len-1] && pal(str+1, len-2));
}
```

Comment: Could be a bit problematic... I usually try not to rely on operands evaluation order since it's not always obvious and easily broken by inexperienced maintainers.

Comment: @icepack: the thought of somebody being a maintainer if they don't know what `||` and `&&` mean is more than a bit scary (at least to me).

Comment: the problem is not with understanding the meaning of `||` and `&&` but with the evaluation order in `C`. As far as pure math is  concerned there is no difference if the left operand is evaluated first or the right. However, there is a big difference during runtime. Your code may be a simple example, but in a more complex cases the problematics might not be so obvious... Sorry if I'm being too picky. By the way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7112282/order-of-evaluation-of-operands

Comment: @icepack: Neither `||` nor `&&` is defined by mathematics. They're C (and C++) operators, and anybody who even touches C or C++ code should certainly know what they mean (including evaluation ordering).

Comment: @icepack: The whole *point* of `&&` and `||` is their evaluation order. How can anyone intentionally use them without knowing their order?!

Comment: @Mehrdad The whole point of `||` and `&&` is to correctly perform the required logical operation. Evaluation order is secondary

Comment: @icepack: But short-circuit evaluation is clearly a *major* part of the definition of the logical operation they perform.

Comment: @JerryCoffin of course, not arguing that. This is however still secondary to performing the actual boolean operation

Comment: @icepack: Not in my mind -- in my mind, if the boolean was the only thing you cared about, you could as well say `!!a & !!b`. People use `&&` *because* of the short-circuiting (and to avoid saying `!`, but that's more minor).

Comment: @Mehrdad People usually use `&&` when they want to express `if a AND b are both true`. Any other usage is a consequence of this, including the short-circuiting that allows not to evaluate `b`.

Comment: @icepack: Well, I disagree. :P

Answer (score 4):

[Here is a working version of your code](http://liveworkspace.org/code/CHvvT%2422).

```
bool pal(const char* str, int length)
{
   if(length <2) return true; // base case - 1 or 0 length string is a palindrome.
   if((*str) == str[length - 1])
   {
     return pal(str+1, length-2); // -2 because 1 from front and 1 from back. 
   }
   else
   {
     return false;
   }
    //no return here because the recursive call is returned.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You check first and last character, so you should decrease length by 2, not by 1. Also, you should return the value of internal pal call, not throw it away.

```
if(*str == str[length - 1])
{
    return pal(str + 1, length - 2);
}
```

An additional test for length being >=2 and str being not null would be in order too.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that you don't do anything with the result of the recursive call:

```
 if(*str == str[length - 1])
    {
        pal(str+1, length-1);
    }
```

should probably be:

```
 if(*str == str[length - 1])
    {
        return pal(str+1, length-1);
    }
```

You also need to check for such things as a zero length string or string with only a single character.

Comment: @icepack: I disagree.  For the initial call, "false" cannot be returned unless the first and last characters are not equal.  Under all other circumstances, "true" is returned for the "main" call.