# Very strange priority/precendence in C++ function

Tags: c++, operator-precedence

Why does the following print out "World Hello!"?

From my understanding, according to operator precedence, this should be evaluated left from right. But instead it seems to be right to left to right. Why is this?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


char print() {
    cout << "World";
    return '!';
}

int main() {
    cout << "Hello " << print() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, wrong link. Should have been [Order of evaluation of operands](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7112282/order-of-evaluation-of-operands?lq=1)

Comment: I apologize, I'm still new to this. I didn't know that topic is relevant to my problem.

Comment: Your understanding is wrong. The order is undefined, i.e. it can be left-to-right, right-to-left, or from the middle outwards zigzagging.

Comment: @Seb - No need to apologize, this is difficult. The operator precedence tells us the order the operators are applied, but not the order the parameters are evaluated. The compiler is allowed to evaluate those in advance, and in no particular order.

Comment: @n.m. You mean unspecified. Using the word "undefined" in a different sense than The Standard's only causes confusion and nitpicking.

Comment: Could it be releated to stream buffering ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not think the standard gives any guarantee about the exact moment when `print()` is called with respect to the application of the `<<` operator.

In your case, it looks like `print()` is called first, then `cout << Hello` is evaluated, and only then `[result of the previous expression] << [result of print()]` is evaluated.

Answer (score 4):

This becomes

```
operator<<
(
    operator<<
    (
        cout,
        "Hello"
    ),
    print()
)
.operator<<
(
    endl
);
```

The order of *evalutation* of arguments is [unspecified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934904/order-of-evaluation-in-c-function-parameters), so there's nothing saying that the innermost `operator<<` has to be evaluated before `print()` in the call to the second-innermost `operator<<`.

Think about it like this: `foo( f1(), f2() );`. Which will be evaluated first, `f1()` or `f2()`? We don't know. We only know that both will be completed before `foo()` runs.

The left-to-right [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) means it ends up paired up the way I wrote it.

**Much later edit:** Slight technical error. The call taking `endl` will actually be a member version. Doesn't make any difference to anything else though.

Answer (score 2):

> this should be evaluated left from right.

It does. You can see it from the `!` at the very end.
But, the final string is printed by `cout` **after** the operators have been evaluated. But, **during** operator evaluation, you are printing `World`. The `Hello!` is then printed afterwards. Hence, you get `WorldHello!`.

As others write, even if it is the result you get (and I could verify it), it might even be undefined behavior with respect to the calling order, since the order of evaluation is unspecified.

@Bo gave a very good link which points to the C++ standard:

```
§5.2.2.8 - [...] The order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified. [...]
```

Answer (score 1):

The order is undefined. Look at *[Order of evaluation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order)*.

```
cout << i << i++; // Undefined behavior
```

Comment: The order of evaluation is *unspecified* which is technically slightly different from *undefined*. And also different from your example.