# Precendence vs short-circuiting in C

Tags: c, short, circuit

```
int i=-3, j=2, k=0, m; 
m = ++i || ++j && ++k; 
printf("%d, %d, %d, %d\n", i, j, k, m);
```

Since `++` has more precedence than `||` and `&&` in C, they are evaluated first and therefore the expression becomes `m = -2 || 3 && 1`. Now you can apply short circuiting but that produces incorrect answer. Why is that?

Comment: omg roflmoa wut iz the prblm herr??

Comment: It's like a party in my eyes and only evil clowns are invited.

Comment: What is the output you are getting and What is output you are expecting?

Comment: @ta.speot.is, you have a grammatical error in roflmoa (grammar nazi)

Comment: Precedence does not imply the order of execution.

Comment: im getting -2 2 0 1 but im expecting -2 3 1 1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5475260/13005

Answer (score 4):

[Precedence ≠ order of evaluation.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/05/23/precedence-vs-associativity-vs-order.aspx)

The short-circuiting behavior of `||` and `&&` means that their left-hand sides are evaluated first, and

- If the LHS of `||` evaluates to true (nonzero), the RHS is not evaluated (because the expression will be `true` no matter what the RHS is)
- If the LHS of `&&` evaluates to false (or zero), the RHS is not evaluated (because the expression will be `false` no matter what the RHS is)

In your example, `++i` gets evaluated, and is equal to -2, which is nonzero, so the right-hand side of the `||` (that is, `++j && ++k`) never gets evaluated: `j` and `k` are never incremented.

Comment: If what we have is `!(++i || ++j && ++k)` instead, does `j` and `k` get incremented?

Answer (score 1):

The `++`s don't execute before the expression. Only `++i` executes, which indicates that the result of the expression will be 1, therefore the rest of the expression is not evaluated (short circuit).

Your code is equivalent to:

```
if (++i)
    m = 1;
else
    if (!++j)
        m = 0;
    else if (!++i)
        m = 0;
    else
        m = 1;
```

This means that once `++i` is evaluated to true, the `else` part is never executed.