# Parentheses and logical operators

Tags: java, c++, logical-operators, short-circuiting

consider this code (C++) :

```
int x = -4 , y = 5 ;
bool result = x > 0 && y++ < 10 ;
```

the expression (x > 0) will be evaluated first , and because (x > 0 = false) and due to short-circuit evaluation , the other expression (y++ < 10) won't be evaluated and the value of y will remain 5 .

now consider the following code :

```
int x = -4 , y = 5 ;
bool result = (x > 0) && (y++ < 10) ;
```

it is expected that the expressions in parentheses will be evaluated first so that before the logical AND is performed , the expression (y++ < 10) would have been evaluated and the value of y has became 6 
 , but the reality is that the value of y remains 5 . which means that even with the parentheses the evaluation is short-circuited and the expression (y++ < 10) is ignored .

What is the explanation for this case ?!

Comment: "It is expected that the expressions in parentheses will be evaluated first" -- **wrong**.  The parentheses don't make a difference, `x > 0` is always evaluated first in both cases.

Comment: Parentheses can override precedence, but [order of evaluation is independent of precedence](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5475260/179910). Order of evaluation is determined by sequence points (C, C++98/03) or ordering constraints (C++11), not precedence or associativity.

Comment: The right side is never evaluated unless the && occurs. While you are correct that parens should be evaluated first in math, boolean logic is a bit different in that it goes left to right guaranteed.

Answer (score 10):

The explanation is in the question - **short-circuiting**.

In C++, evaluation of `&&` (and `||` for that matter) is guaranteed to be left-to-right, and as soon as a `false` is encountered (respectively `true` for `||`), evaluation is **guaranteed** to stop.

Similar for Java I guess.

The parenthesis are redundant and not relevant in this case - it has nothing to do with operator precedence. It simply has to do with how `&&` works:

In fact, the two versions

```
x > 0 && y++ < 10
(x > 0) && (y++ < 10)
```

are equivalent, because `++` has the highest precedence, followed by `<,>`, and finally `&&`. Pedantically, you should have written it as:

```
(x > 0) && ((y++) < 10)
```

#### 5.14 Logical AND operator [expr.log.and]

> 1 The `&&` operator groups left-to-right. The operands are both implicitly converted to type bool (clause 4). The result
>   is true if both operands are `true` and `false` otherwise. **Unlike &, && guarantees left-to-right evaluation: the second
>   operand is not evaluated if the first operand is `false`.** (emphasis mine)

Comment: FYI Java has the non-short-circuited AND (`&`) and OR (`|`).

Comment: @SteveKuo those are bitwise operators, and the C++ versions too are non-short-circuiting.

Answer (score 1):

When the left side determines the result, the right side is not evaluated.

In the first case, the right side is `y++ < 10`, and this is not evaluated. In the second case, the right side is `(y++ < 10)`, and this is not evaluated.

There is no rule that expressions in parentheses are evaluated first. Parentheses only group operands.

Answer (score 0):

Even with parentheses short-circuiting *must* still take place. Consider if you have an expression involving pointers:

```
int* ptr = 0;
int bar = 5;
bool result = (ptr != 0) && (*ptr == bar || bar > 10);
```

You clearly can't safely evaluate the right-hand side of the `&&` there, but the parentheses are required to make the precedence work as intended. The parentheses simply determine the order of operations *that are actually performed* not that they happen in a particular order.