# C Operator Precedence, post-increment programming issue

Tags: c, operators, post-increment, operator-precedence

Can some one explain why the output of program is

**`0 1 1 3 1`**

```
void main(void)
{
      int i=-1,j=0,k=1,l=2,m;

      m=i++&&j++&&k++||l++;

      printf("%d %d %d %d %d",i,j,k,l,m);

}
```

Main concern is "why k is not incremented".

FYI..I am compiling the program in VC++ editor Windows 7 32 bit.
Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's better to use parenthesis for complex expressions. Use parenthesis the way you want to evaluate expressions.

Comment: See e.g. [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: Nothing drives me more nostalgic than `void main()`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Operator Precedence vs Order of Evaluation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473107/operator-precedence-vs-order-of-evaluation)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Roughly:

To evaluate `i++&&j++`, compiler evaluated `i` first. The result is `-1`. `-1` is stored in a temporary variable. Then `i` got incremented.

Because `-1` is not zero, compiler evaluated `j`, which is `0`. Compiler now evaluated `-1 && 0`, which is `0`. Then `j` got incremented.

At this point, `i = 0` and `j = 1`. Remaining expression: `m=0&&k++||l++;`

To evaluate `0&&k++`, compiler noted that the first operand is `0`. The result must be `0` so compiler didn't evaluate `k` or `k++`. Remaining expression: `m=0||l++;`

I hope you can do the rest. :)

Comment: Thanks for explaining why k is not incremented!

Answer (score 4):

Lets break this down into its separate operations:

1. `i++ && j++`: This will be the same as `-1 && 0`, which is false (i.e. 0).
2. `i` and `j` are then increased to `0` and `1` respectively.
3. `0 && k++`: The zero is from the previous logical operation, the result is false since the first operator is false.
4. `k` is **not** increased, because of the shortcut nature of the logical operators.
5. `0 || l`: The zero is still from the previous logic operation, it is `0 || 2` and the result will be true, i.e. `1`.
6. `l` is increased to `3`.
7. The result of the logical operations is assigned to `m`, which now becomes true (i.e. `1`)

The whole expression causes `i`, `j` and `l` to be increased, and `m` to become `1`. Just the result you are seeing.

Comment: k is not increased, because of the shortcut nature of the logical operators ---> how is it decided?

Comment: @PowerPC In an expression such a `0 && 1`, the result is guaranteed to be `0`, and so the right hand side of the `&&` operator needs not be evaluated. Same with `1 || 0`, it will always be `1` and the same thing happens. This is all specified in the C specification.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg : +1 for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

your value is getting calculated like below

```
m=((((i++)&&j++)&&k++)||l++);
```

since all ++ are post increment so during calculation of m all variable have same value what you have initialised but on the next line during print they all are incremented.Last is || so final TRUE will return to value of m.