# PHP bug with ternary operator?

Tags: php, operator-keyword, ternary

```
function foo() {
    return $result = bar() ? $result : false;
}

function bar() {
    return "some_value";
}

foo();
```

> Notice: Undefined variable: result

Is this a bug?

bar() should be saved to $result, but it doesn't. However the condition works fine and it's trying to return $result or false statement (in case bar() is NULL or false)

PHP 5.4.24

Comment: Why is this a bug, its trying to read $result but it isnt defined so is telling you its undefined.  Seems like by Design to me.

Comment: It is getting value from `bar()` so return `true` => thus assigning `$result` which is undefined. What's wrong with that ?

Comment: Obvious PICNIC going on here.. :)

Comment: see [incorrect associativity of ternary operator](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61915)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's because [operators precedence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php). Do

```
function foo() {
    return ($result = bar()) ? $result : false;
}
```

-so assignment will be evaluated with higher precedence.

Comment: Great! Yep.. without parentheses it returns $result as evaluation of subsequent condition. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

more elegant solution:

```
function foo() {
    return bar() ?: false; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't we do just:

```
function foo() {
    return bar() ? $result : false;
}

function bar() {
    return "some_value";
}

foo();
```

Comment: .. and you'll get undefined `$result` variable (because you'll try to return it)

Answer (score 0):

Using the side-effect of a sub-expression within the same expression is always risky, even if the operator precedence is correct.

Even if it's necessary to *evaluate the result of* `$result = bar()` in order to test the condition, there's no general guarantee that that result will be used later in the expression, rather than a value taken before the assignment.

See for instance [Operator Precedence vs Order of Evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473107/operator-precedence-vs-order-of-evaluation) which discusses this in the context of C++, and gives this classic example:

```
a = a++ + ++a;
```

Having side-effects inside a condition is also hard to read - it might be read as `$result == bar()`, which would mean something entirely different.

So, in this case, the problem was just PHP's unfortunate associativity of `? :`, but writing code like this is a bad idea anyway, and you can trivially make it much more readable and reliable by taking the side-effect out of the left-hand side:

```
$result = bar();
return $result ? $result : false;
```

Or in this case, assuming `$result` is not `global` or `static`:

```
return bar() ?: false;
```