# Precedence of operators?

Tags: c++, operator-precedence

Look at this simple class:

```
class A {
    int *val;
public:
    A() { val = new int; *val = 0; }
    int get() { return ++(*val); }
};
```

Why when I run this code it prints `21`:

```
int main() {
    A a, b = a;
    cout << a.get() << b.get();
    return 0;
}
```

But if I run it like this it prints `12` which is what I was expecting:

```
int main() {
    A a, b = a;
    cout << a.get();
    cout << b.get();
    return 0;
}
```

What am I missing here? Operator precedence? FYI, this is a C++ test problem, not a production code.

**EDIT:**
Does it means that when I have `cout << (Expr1) << (Expr2)` then `Expr1` and `Expr2` are evaluated before the output of `Expr1` is printed?

Comment: This is about associativity, not precedence. There is only one operator, so the question of precedence cannot arise.

Comment: The first one could print `12` also depending on the compiler you use.

Comment: This is not about associativity. This is about order of evaluation of sub-expressions.

Comment: @T.C. Which is determined by associativity, if it's defined at all.

Comment: @EJP No, it's not. It's generally unspecified.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473107/operator-precedence-vs-order-of-evaluation

Comment: C++11 (draft N3337) _dcl.fct.default_: `The order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified.`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Operator precedence does not dictate the order of evaluation of intermediate results. I.e. it does not dictate the order of evaluation of sub-expressions in the entire expression.

Expression statement

```
cout << a.get() << b.get();
```

can be executed by the compiler as

```
int tmp_a = a.get();
int tmp_b = b.get();
cout << tmp_a;
cout << tmp_b;
```

or as

```
int tmp_b = b.get();
int tmp_a = a.get();
cout << tmp_a;
cout << tmp_b;
```

In this case operator precedence and associativity for operator `<<` guarantees that `tmp_a` is *sent to output* before `tmp_b`. But it does not guarantee that `tmp_a` is *evaluated* before `tmp_b`.

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
cout << a.get() << b.get();
```

does not specify whether `a.get()` or `b.get()` is evaluated first.

Since `a` and `b` share the same `val` pointer, the order of those operations affect the output.

(Edit)

> Does it means that when I have cout << (Expr1) << (Expr2) then Expr1 and Expr2 are evaluated before the output of Expr1 is printed?

That is also not specified.

Comment: Done! However I'm still not clear why `Expr2` is being evaluated before `Expr1`. I have tried GCC and MSVC

Comment: @DarienPardinas it's because they want to, and they're allowed to.  You, as a programmer, are not to assume which will be evaluated first.  And if you want that control, you can put them on separate lines.  Good luck!

Comment: @DarienPardinas Don't confused *observed* behavior with *specified* behavior or *defined* behavior. They're sometimes different things. When in doubt peel back the standard text and see where it takes you.

Comment: Thanks! Anyway, that was one of the practice questions of the C++ Certified Associate Programmer and the right answer according to them is `21` even when that output should be undefined.

Comment: @DarienPardinas Wow!  Someone should have a chat with them, no?  Can you share a link?

Comment: http://education.cppinstitute.org/ Chapter 6 Question 7. You need to register (it's free) to see it with your own eyes.

Comment: @DarienPardinas their stock photos use differing gaussian blurs.  That's the first red flag.

Comment: @DrewDormann What yo you mean with that? That is not worth looking at this certification?