# C++: Associativity of * (multiply) operator is not left-to-right

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operator-keyword, associativity

While working on a school assignment, we had to do something with operator overloading and templates. All cool. I wrote:

```
template<class T>
class Multiplication : public Expression<T>
{
private:
        typename std::shared_ptr<Expression<T> > l, r;

public:
        Multiplication(typename std::shared_ptr<Expression<T> > l, typename std::shared_ptr<Expression<T> > r) : l(l), r(r) {};
        virtual ~Multiplication() {};

        T evaluate() const
        {
                std::cout << "*";
                T ml = l->evaluate();
                T mr = r->evaluate();
                return ml * mr;
        };
};
```

Then a friend asked me why his code produced output in the "wrong" order.
He had something like

```
T evaluate() const
{
        std::cout << "*";
        return l->evaluate() * r->evaluate();
};
```

The code of `r->evaluate()` printed the debug information, before `l->evaluate()`.
I tested it on my machine as well, by just changing these three lines to a one-liner.

So, I thought, well then `*` should be right-to-left associative. But everywhere on the internet they say it is left-to-right. Are there some extra rules? Maybe something special when using templates? Or is this a bug in VS2012 ?

Comment: Associativity is not the same as order of evaluation.

Comment: Seems like that is the key :) I'll do some research, thanks already.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Operator Precedence vs Order of Evaluation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473107/operator-precedence-vs-order-of-evaluation)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When we say the associativity of `*` is left-to-right, we mean that the expression `a*b*c*d` will always evaluate as `(((a*b)*c)*d)`. That's it. In your example, you only have one `operator*`, so there isn't anything to associate.

What you're running into is the order of evaluation of operands. You are calling:

```
operator*(l->evaluate(), r->evaluate());
```

Both expressions need to be evaluated before the call to `operator*`, but it is unspecified (explicitly) by the C++ standard what order they get evaluated in. In your case, `r->evaluate()` got evaluated first - but that has nothing to do with the associativity of `operator*`.

Note that even if you had `a->evaluate() * b->evaluate() * c->evaluate()`, that would get parsed as:

```
operator*(operator*(a->evaluate(), b->evaluate()), c->evaluate())
```

based on the rules of operator associativity - but even in that case, there's no rule to prevent `c->evaluate()` from being called first. It may very well be!

Answer (score 2):

You have a single operator in your expression:

```
l->evaluate() * r->evaluate()
```

so associativity is not involved at all here. The catch is that the two operands are evaluated before calling the `*` operator and the order in which they are evaluated is not defined. A compiler is allowed to reorder the evaluation in any suitable way.

In C++11 terms, the call to `operator*` is sequenced after the operand evaluation, but there is no sequence relation between the two evaluations. From the [n4296 draft (post C++14)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf), page 10:

> **§1.9.15** Except where noted, evaluations of operands of individual operators and of subexpressions of individual expressions are unsequenced.