# Order of evaluation in C (for expression with * and ++)

Tags: c, operator-precedence, postfix-operator

If we have

```
int i = 5; /*line 1*/
int *p = &i; /*line 2*/
*p++; /*line 3*/
```

What is the order of evaluation for line 3?
(I know that after this p might point to something weird - but I'm not interested in the correct memory addressing but the order of evaluation, as both * and ++ seems to have same precedence)

Comment: No they don't have the same precedence. Postfix form ++ has higher precedence than *, unlike prefix form.

Comment: A simple way to remember that `++` increments the pointer is to note the usual single-line strcpy implementation: `while(*dst++ = *src++);` which would fail if `++` incremented actual characters instead of pointers.

Comment: Operator precedence is a [discoverable thing](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I used the precendence table from "C Programming Language" (K&R page 48) where * and ++ sit on the same row.

Answer (score 4):

No, [postfix increment has higher precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

In your case, the side-effect of the increment will take place after the value evaluation <sup>note</sup> (with the dereference operator). The result of the value evaluation, though, is discarded (you did not make any effort to store the result).

So, finally, the result will be the *equivalent* as `p++;`

---

Note:

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.2.4, (*emphasis mine*)

> **The result of the postfix `++` operator is the value of the operand**. As a side effect, the
>   value of the operand object is incremented (that is, the value 1 of the appropriate type is
>   added to it). See the discussions of additive operators and compound assignment for
>   information on constraints, types, and conversions and the effects of operations on
>   pointers. **The value computation of the result is sequenced before the side effect of
>   updating the stored value of the operand.** [...]

Comment: So, even if ++ (by having a higher precedence) should be evaluated first it is postponed until the *p is evaluated?

Comment: @Alex Yes, the "increment" is a side effect, the value of the postfix `++` is the value of the operand itself, as already highlighted in my answer.

Comment: @Alex - Indeed - evaluation order and precedence are essentially unrelated; see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5475260/129570.

Answer (score 0):

`*p++` is treated as `*(p++)` because precedence of postfix `++` is **higher** than `*`.

Comment: are you sure about this?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Yes sir.

Comment: @SouravGhosh - Semantically it's a correct assessment. A compiler will probably sequence the load before the increment, but for the C abstraction as defined by the standard `*p++` is semantically equivalent to `*(p++)`, as **rsp** said.

Comment: @StoryTeller and rsp - Correct, thanks for confirming. :)

Comment: Why then all string functions are done like this: `while (*str) something = *str++`. If string is `abcd` then values set to `something`needed to be `bcd` according to your answer and all the comments! `*p++`is evaluated in a ways that it is first read/write of current `p` address and then increment is executed.

Answer (score -2):

You have to put parenthesis around the *p for this to work:

```
int i = 5; /*line 1*/
int *p = &i; /*line 2*/
(*p)++; /*line 3*/ 
printf("Hello, World! %d\n", *p);
```

See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Comment: For *what* to work? The OP didn't specify what he wishes was to happen, only asking how those three lines are evaluated.

Comment: You're right. In fact OP should just have compiled and run a few variations on operator precedence, and see how they matched expectations. Oh, well - SO is not an easy game to win points on! :-)