# C++ unary right fold vs unary left fold with comma operator

Tags: c++, c++17, fold-expression

Why comma separated unary left fold produce the same result as the right one?

[Live code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d646cd374d9759e9)

```
template<class ...Args>
void right_fold(Args... args){
    ((std::cout << args),...);
}

template<class ...Args>
void left_fold(Args... args){
    (...,(std::cout << args));
}

int main()
{
    right_fold(1,2,3,4);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    left_fold(1,2,3,4);
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
1234
1234
```

Shouldn't it be:

```
4321
1234
```

?

Comment: Simply put, recedence and order of evaluation is independent

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Operator Precedence vs Order of Evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473107/operator-precedence-vs-order-of-evaluation)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Left vs right folding is the difference between `((a,b),c)` and `(a,(b,c))`, but they have exactly the same effect when the built-in `,` operator is used: they first evaluate `a`, then `b` and finally `c`. To see a difference, you'd need to use a type with a custom overloaded `,` operator.

The syntax may look as if it would reverse the arguments, but no, that won't happen.

Comment: Why both `((a,b),c)` and `(a,(b,c))` have the same execution order?

Comment: @tower120 [A pair of expressions separated by a comma is evaluated left-to-right;](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.comma#1.sentence-2).

Comment: @tower120 The first means "first, evaluate a then b, then, evaluate c". The second means "first, evaluate a, then evaluate b then c". The net effect is the same.

Comment: @tower120 What order do you expect in each case and why?

Comment: So... parentheses don't work with commas?...  I expected to see a,b,c order for ((a,b),c) because a,b in the deepest parentheses level, and left to right a then b.   And b,c,a for (a,(b,c))  because b,c in the deepest level, left to right b then c.

Comment: @tower120 Parentheses do work, but they never pretty much never specify evaluation order. This is no different from other operators. Given `f() * (g() + h())`, `f`, `g` and `h` may be called in any order. There is no requirement to call `g` and `h` first.

Comment: So if not this special rule http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.comma#1.sentence-2 , order of evaluation (in case with comma) would be unspecified / compiler dependent?

Comment: @tower120 Exactly. There are a few operators which force left-to-right evaluation, and those are called out specifically in the standard. As of C++17, there are some operators which force right-to-left evaluation, and those are also called out in the standard. For the other operators, the order is entirely up to the implemention.

Answer (score 4):

These folds respectively expand to:

```
((std::cout << 1), ((std::cout << 2), ((std::cout << 3), (std::cout << 4))))
```

... and:

```
((((std::cout << 1), (std::cout << 2)), (std::cout << 3)), (std::cout << 4))
```

Despite the flurry of parentheses, they are equivalent in terms of order of execution: left to right.

Answer (score 4):

Because they are indeed the same thing:

```
((std::cout << 1, std::cout << 2), std::cout << 3), std::cout << 4;
std::cout << 1, (std::cout << 2, (std::cout << 3, std::cout << 4));
```

Both have output `1234`.