# Is there a difference between precedence and order of operation execution during the runtime?

Tags: c, low-level

I want to know whether the CPU executes operations instructions during runtime in the same sequence obeying rules used in precedence to evaluate a value of an expression or not.

Comment: The CPU does not have that concept - it is a language construct. The CPU executes instruction serially.

Comment: @WeatherVane Does this mean rules of precedence can be somehow broken depending on the machine and the compiler implementation and optimization settings ?

Comment: There is a big difference between what the CPU does, and how the compiler prepares instructions for it. The CPU does not care *which* language prepared the code. Of interest may be [Operator Precedence vs Order of Evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473107/operator-precedence-vs-order-of-evaluation)

Comment: The compiler will make sure that the machine code follows the precedence rules if it matters.

Comment: @WeatherVane
Thanks a lot , Shall I remove the question ?

Comment: @MohamedAtef I think you could let the question stay

Comment: @klutt No one was born great :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things to clarify. A C source code is "translated" into machine code by the compiler. There is never a 1 to 1 relationship between C code/instructions and machine code/instructions.

When compiling code the only thing that matters is the [as if rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if). As long as the observable behavior of the program is preserved, the compiler can generate instructions in any order.

Furthermore, on the hardware level, the CPU has its own mechanism for detecting instruction dependencies and can itself execute instructions out of order or in parallel (e.g. a single core has more than 1 [ALU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_logic_unit) and [FPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_unit)).

So, for a correct C program, the observable behavior of the program will be preserved. Instructions can be reordered, parts of code completely skipped and even algorithms completely changed underneath (e.g. modern compilers can transform recursive functions into non-recursive functions with loop constructs). But the observable behavior of the program will not change.

Comment: Also the order of evaluation is unrelated to the operator precedence, giving the compiler even more freedom.

Comment: C++ has nothing to do with this question without a C++ tag.

Comment: *execute instructions out of order* ... while preserving the *illusion* / appearance of serial execution, at least for a single thread, the HW version of the as-if rule. Usually that goes without saying, but perhaps worth mentioning here. See  [How can we expect a program to complete in order?](//stackoverflow.com/q/64276544).and links in that answer, especially http://www.lighterra.com/papers/modernmicroprocessors/, and [this Q&A](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/349972/how-does-a-single-thread-run-on-multiple-cores/350024#350024) about OoO superscalar exec basics.

Comment: It would never happen in practice, but in principle, the compiler is free to change a bubble sort to a quick sort if it can guarantee that the observable behavior is equivalent.

Comment: @klutt: Other kinds of pattern-recognition do happen.  clang recognizes `sum(i=0..n)` loops and compiles it to Gauss's closed-form with a multiply https://godbolt.org/z/T6KKeM.  Some compilers are also able to recognize bit-count loops and compile to a `popcnt` instruction, or `(x>>n) | (x<<-n)` into a rotate.    Some compilers "defeat" SPECint2006's `libquantum` benchmark by inverting a loop (so the memory access pattern doesn't suck).  https://www.realworldtech.com/forum/?threadid=102569&curpostid=102580