# How do I make a custom operator evaluate left-to-right?

Tags: c++, custom-operator

I want to evaluate `a()|b()` left-to-right, but I get a different order depending on whether I use the built-in operator or a custom operator.

```
    class Foo {
        public: Foo operator| (Foo f) {
            return Foo();
        }
    };
    std::string out;
    auto f1 = [&out](std::string s) { out += s; return false; };
    auto f2 = [&out](std::string s) { out += s; return Foo(); };
    f1("a") | f1("b");
    f2("c") | f2("d");
    std::cout << out;
```

The output is `abdc`. How do I make the custom operator evaluate left-to-right?

Comment: Evaluation order of subexpressions is mostly unspecified in C++, with some variation across C++ standards (and explicitly specified order, i.e. short circuit with booleans). You cannot change evaluation order with overloaded operators, which use the same evaluation order rules whether the operator is overloaded, or not.

Comment: Operands of `|` evaluate in unspecified order, no matter if builtin or not. Pick a different operator that enforces order, like `<<`,`>>`.

Comment: You are probably mixing `|` (an arithmetic operator wioth unspecified order of evaluation) with `||` (a boolean operator which does evaluate left-to-right and performs short-circuit evaluation if built-in)

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot `|` is used in many contexts as "non-short-circuiting `||`". I wanted to use both options, with `||` taking a lambda argument to preserve short-circuiting.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat How can I find out whether an operator enforces order? I want to have both a `foo1 | foo2` operator and a short-circuiting `foo1 || [](){ return foo2 }` version.

Comment: The Evaluation Order rules are spelled out here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order#Rules including which operators define an order.

Comment: @H.v.M. *"`|` is used in many contexts as 'non-short-circuiting `||`'. I wanted to use both options"* -- Non-short-circuiting implies the operands can be evaluated in any order (because both will be evaluated). Trying to force left-to-right evaluation is asking for more than the built-in operator guarantees. Why do you care about left-to-right evaluation when there is no short circuiting intended?

Comment: @JaMiT So that the side effects happen in the correct order. The idea is that all instrument controller functions return an `ErrorMessage` type which is the wrapper of a string vector of error messages. `|` is supposed to combine the error messages, and it has the correct logical meaning since `int()` is overridden so that `if (error)` may be used as "if any error".

Comment: Offtopic: why you want overload operators at all? The cases where this makes seance are quite rare. Code which overloads operators without good reason is harder to read and maintain. From my observation many beginners often are jumping to fast on this language feature.

Comment: @H.v.M. *"So that the side effects happen in the correct order."* -- If you want to order side-effects of sub-expressions, you have the wrong language. The principle that function arguments can be evaluated in any order goes back to C, before C++ was developed. The few exceptions (such as short-circuiting) are just that, exceptions to the general rule. *Lengthy Q&A on the subject: [Operator Precedence vs Order of Evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5473107)*

Comment: If the order of evaluation really matters, just use multiple statements and don't mess around with operators (or operator overloading).  As in `f1("a"); f1("b");` instead of `f1("a") | f1("b");` and `f2("c"); f2("d");` instead of `f2("c") | f1("d");`.    All expressions in an expression statement are evaluated before executing the next statement so, unlike most operators, evaluation order is guaranteed.

Comment: @JaMiT Rather than call them exceptions, it seems more accurate to say that the principle applies to functions but not to operators.

Comment: Something you could do to print the strings in the right order is to store a pointer to the output string and the argument strings in the `Foo` object and append them in the implementation of `operator|` in the desired order.

Comment: @H.v.M. *"it seems more accurate to say that the principle applies to functions but not to operator"* -- No, that would be false. The principle applies to both operators and functions. It applies to `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `%`, `&`, `|`, `^`, `==`, `!=`, `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`, and `<=>`. It does not apply to `&&` and `||`. The shorter list would be the exceptions, no? *(I probably missed some operators, but I think not enough to change the conclusion.)*

Comment: I suppose you could modify your `ErrorMessage` type to include a `std::function` to call. The bodies of your `f1()` functions could become lambdas that are stored in these returned objects. Then your `operator|` could invoke the stored functions as needed. A bit convoluted and going against the normal flow of the language, but it could work. Maybe. I don't have time to see if it works right now, but others can follow-up if they want.

Comment: @JaMiT Some other ordered operators are `<<` , `>>` , `,`, `+=` (and all other assignment operators), and (interpreting 'operator' broadly) subscript and pointer-to-member expressions `E1[E2]`, `E1.*E2`, `E1->*E2`.

Comment: In the end I decided to use `e = f1(); e += f2();` to combine results and `e |= []() { return f3(); };` for the short-circuiting variant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. At least not with an overloaded `operator|`. The evaluation order of operands to functions and most operators in unspecified in C++.

For the built-in `||`, operator order is left-to-right, but you cannot overload that operator to return anything but `bool` because it would cease to be "built-in `||`".
If you give your `Foo` class an `operator bool() const` which converts to `bool`, then you can write `f2("x") || f2("y")` but the right expression will not be evaluated if the left evaluates to true, *and* it will very likely emit a branch instruction in the compiler's output.

You could overload `operator,` (or use the built-in) as well, which then would be sequenced in the way you are looking for.

[More details](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order):

> 6. Every value computation and side effect of the first (left) argument of the built-in logical AND operator &&, the built-in logical OR operator || and the built-in comma operator , is sequenced before every value computation and side effect of the second (right) argument.
> 7. Every value computation and side effect associated with the first expression in the conditional operator ?: is sequenced before every value computation and side effect associated with the second or third expression.